# Making Unix shell scripts POSIX compliant

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have been working on a shell script to automate some tasks. What is the best way to make sure the shell script would run without any issues in most of the platforms. For ex., I have been using `echo -n` command to print some messages to the screen without a trailing new line and the `-n` switch doesn't work in some ksh shells. I was told the script must be POSIX compliant. How do I make sure that the script is POSIX compliant. Is there a tool? Or is there a shell that supports only bare minimum POSIX requirements?

Comment: [This UnixSE question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/how-can-i-test-for-posix-compliance-for-shell-scripts) has some good feedback.

Comment: Remember that one part of the shell script portability (POSIX-compliance) problem is the shell notation used.  The other half of the problem is using the portable (POSIX-compliant) options to the POSIX commands and not accidentally using GNU extensions to the POSIX commands.  It is quite hard to avoid such problems on occasion.  You'll also need to make a decision on whether such non-POSIX tools as Perl or Python can ever be used.

Answer (score 15):

## POSIX

One first step, which gives you indications of what works or not and **why**, is to set the shebang to `/bin/sh` and [use the  ShellCheck site](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to analyze your script.
For example, paste this script in the ShellCheck editor window:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -r a b <<<"$1"
echo $((a+b))
```

to get an indication that: "In POSIX sh, here-strings are undefined".

As a second step, you can use a shell that is as compatible with POSIX as possible.
One shell that is compatible with most other simple shells, [is dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), Debian default system shell, which is a derivative of the older BSD ash.

Another shell compatible with POSIX is posh.

However, dash and/or posh may not be available for some systems.

There is lksh (with a ksh flavor), with the goal to be compatible with legacy (old) shell scripts. From its manual:

> lksh is a command interpreter intended exclusively for running legacy shell scripts.

But there is the need to use options when calling lksh, like `-o posix` and `-o sh`:

> Note that it's strongly recommended to invoke lksh with at least the -o posix option, if not both that and -o sh, to fully enjoy better compatibility to the POSIX standard (which is probably why you use lksh over mksh in the first place) or legacy scripts, respectively.

You would call `lksh -o posix -o sh` instead of the simple `lksh`.

Using options is a way to make other shells become POSIX compatible. Like lksh, using the option `-o posix`, like `bash -o posix`.

In bash, it is even possible to turn the POSIX option on inside a script, with:

```
shopt -o posix            # also with: set -o posix
```

It is also possible to make a local link to `bash` or `zsh` that makes both act like an old `sh` shell. Like this:

```
$ ln -s /bin/bash ./sh
$ ./sh
```

There are plenty of alternatives (dash, posh, lksh, bash, zsh, etc.) to get a shell that will work as a POSIX shell.

## Portable

However, even so, all the above does not ensure "portability".

Unfortunately, making a shell script 'POSIX-compliant' is usually easier than making it run on any real-world shell.

The only real-world sensible recommendation is test your script in several shells.
Like the list above: `dash`, `posh`, `lksh`, and `bash --posix`.

Solaris is a world on its own, probably you will need to test against /bin/sh and xpg4/sh.

Followup:

[How can I test for POSIX compliance for shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48786/190466)

Comment: "Unfortunately, making a shell script 'POSIX-compliant' is usually easier than making it run on any real-world shell." Shouldn't that be the other way round? Such as: "Unfortunately, making a shell script 'POSIX-compliant' is usually **harder** than making it run on any real-world shell."

Answer (score 1):

Starting Bash with the --posix command-line option or executing ‘set -o posix’ while Bash is running will cause Bash to conform more closely to the POSIX standard by changing the behavior to match that specified by POSIX in areas where the Bash default differs.

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html)

Comment: That's helpful, but the key phrase is _more closely_: many Bashisms are still available even when Bash is running in POSIX compatibility mode (e.g., `[[ ... ]]` conditionals, `<<<…` (here-strings), …), so by itself
this won't tell you whether a script is POSIX-compliant. To put it differently: While using Bash with `--posix`, `set -o posix` or invoking it as `sh` eliminates some outright incompatibilities with the POSIX spec., it still  permits many  Bash-specific extensions that will break with mostly-POSIX-features only shells such as `dash`.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- This answer *complements* [user8017719's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40922501/45375).
- As requested in the question, a *tool* is discussed below: while it does *not* directly check for POSIX compliance, it runs a given script in *multiple shells*, notably including `/bin/sh`.

  - `/bin/sh`, the system default shell, should not be assumed to support any features other than POSIX-prescribed ones, though in practice it does, to varying degrees, depending on the specific implementation. Therefore, successfully running via `/bin/sh` on one platform does *not* guarantee that the script will work on another. Among widely used shells, `dash` comes closest to being a POSIX-features-only shell.
  - Running successfully in *multiple* shells is important:

    - if you're authoring a script that needs to be *sourced* in various shells.
    - if you know that your script will encounter only a limited set of known-in-advance shells.

---

For a [proof-of-the-pudding-is-in-the-eating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_proof_of_the_pudding_is_in_the_eating) approach, **consider using [`shall`](https://github.com/mklement0/shall)** (a utility I wrote), which **allows you to invoke a given script or command with *multiple* shells *at once***, with feedback about which of the targeted shells the script/command executed successfully with.

If you have Node.js installed, you can easily install it with `npm install -g shall` (if not, follow the above link to the GitHub repo for manual installation instructions) and then use it as follows:

```bash
shall scriptFile
```

or, with an ad-hoc command:

```bash
shall -c '<shell-commands>'
```

By default, it invokes `sh`, and, if installed, `dash`, `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh`, but **you can target any set of shells that you have installed** by using the `SHELLS` environment variable.

Using the example of the `echo -n` command on macOS to only target shells `sh` and `bash`:

```bash
$ SHELLS=sh,bash shall -c 'echo -n hi'
✓ sh (bash variant)                       [0.00s]
  -n hi

✓ bash                                    [0.00s]
  hi

OK - All 2 shells (sh, bash) report success.
```

On macOS, `bash` (effectively) acts as `sh`, and while `echo -n` didn't *fail* when used with `sh`, you can also see that `-n` wasn't recognized as an *option* when `bash` ran as `sh`.

Another macOS example that shows that `bash` permits certain Bash-specific extensions even when running as `sh`, such as using nonstandard `[[ ... ]]` conditionals (assumes that `dash` - which acts as `sh` on Ubuntu systems - was installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)):

```bash
$ SHELLS=sh,bash,dash shall -c '[[ -n nonempty ]] && echo nonempty'
✓ sh (bash variant)                       [0.00s]
  nonempty

✓ bash                                    [0.00s]
  nonempty

✗ dash                                    [0.01s]
  dash: 1: [[: not found

FAILED - 1 shell (dash) reports failure, 2 (sh, bash) report success.
```

As you can see, Bash running as `sh` still accepted `[[ ... ]]`, whereas `dash`, which is a (mostly) POSIX-features-only shell, *failed*, because POSIX only mandates `[ ... ]` conditionals (as an alias of `test ...` commands).